# How to use a microsecond precision timestamp field as a cursor with Prisma?

Tags: typescript, database, timestamp, prisma

I have creted a field that uses microsecond precision to be used as a cursor when paginating:

```
createdAt DateTime @unique @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(6)
```

but my problem is that the `Date` type only supports millisecond precision. How can I use this field with Prisma? I get a `Date` back if I query my records.